# How to find the angle between two triangles when there is involved the sum of two sides not adjacent?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows a triangle $ABC$. Find the angle $x$ on
> $\angle BCA$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&20^{\circ}\\
2.&12^{\circ}\\
3.&15^{\circ}\\
4.&16^{\circ}\\
5.&18^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

This problem seems to be approached forming an isosceles by an auxiliary construction or something by drawing a line from $A$ to a point $P$ in $BC$. But I dont know if that's the right approach for this. Can someone help me exactly how to relate it with the sum of the sides given in the triangle?.

Please an answer which would help me the most is some which is not relying on trigonometry. Can someone help me with a drawing to solve this thing?.

Comment: What book are you getting these problems from?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Hi, sorry. Btw I browsed your deviantart page and weasyl pages and they're cool. I also enjoy drawing vector art, my tool of choice is Inkscape. Since you're interested in where I got these problems. They are from an older math puzzles book which encompasses a collection of riddles and recreational problems in all sorts of topics from maths. Hopefully it has a reference page at the end from which I believe they used to get some of these problems.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Continued from ..., one of the books listed is [Stanley R. Clemens, Phares G. O'Daffer, Thomas J. Cooney, John A. Dossey's Geometry](https://www.amazon.com/Addison-Wesley-Geometry-Teachers-Stanley-Clemens/dp/0201812614/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=clemens+geometry&qid=1603666446&sr=8-2) the other is [Charles D. Miller, Vern E. Heeren, John Hornsby, Mathematical Ideas](https://www.iberlibro.com/9781256719625/MATHEMATICAL-IDEAS-CUSTOM-MillerHeerenHornsby-1256719625/plp), with contents also from [here](https://i.imgur.com/4pcEx36.jpg)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Continued from ..., and [Moise and Down's Geometry](https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Teachers-Moise-Downs/dp/0201050293/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=moise+downs+geometry&qid=1603665119&sr=8-2) the other which they also list is [Richard E. Johnson; Lona Lee Lendsey; William E. Slesnick; Grace E. Bates Algebra and Trigonometry](https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Trigonometry-Solution-Richard-Johnson/dp/B001DR219M)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Continued from ..., and [Let's Play Math by Michael Holt, Zoltan Dienes and Martin Gardner's Mathematical magic show](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Magic-Show-Sleight-Mind/dp/0394408225) and its [classic](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Magic-Mystery-Dover-Recreational/dp/0486203352), which by the name looks in line with what your characters show. I hope this may have answered your question. Best regards and hope we can keep exchanging learning ideas in the future. Btw, I'm a science supersentai fan, hence my avatar!. :)

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

Construct point $E$ on $\overline{AC}$ s.t. $\overline{AB}=\overline{BE}$. Therefore $\angle AEB=2x\Longrightarrow \angle EBC=x\Longrightarrow\overline{BE}=\overline{EC}$.

Step 2:

Construct $\triangle EFC$ ($\triangle EFC\cong\triangle ADB$) as shown in the picture. We then know that $B, F, E$ are on the same line because

1. $\angle DEB=\angle FEC$
2. $D,E,C$ are also on the same line

Step 3:

Note that $\overline{AD}=\overline{EF}$ and $\overline{AB}=\overline{BE}$. Therefore $\overline{BE}+\overline{EF}=\overline{BF}=\overline{BC}$. At this point we know that $\triangle BFC$ is an isosceles with base angle $4x$.

Hence we have $9x=180^{\circ}\Longrightarrow x=20^{\circ}$.

[image]

Comment: Howdy!. Thanks you're my savior. I didn't know you're from TW. I love Taipei, I longed to visit and study in NTU since my major is chemistry. The construction which you have made below the triangle is very clever, I didn't imagined such can be done. But I wonder, can this be solved by using similarity or congruence?.

Comment: I am not sure about this. At least I am not able to come up with a solution using them.